# DL image preparation - resizing

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, data-processing

I've got some tasks about classification and Object ROI.
So I got images and labels like class and x1,y2,x2,y2 (standard box)
But images are different in sizes, is there some solution to get box coordinates after resizing?

So what i mean - i got image 300 px H and 400 px W  and box coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2). Before train my Dl model - i have to resize all images to the same W and H, for example I choose 200*200, so is there some solution to calculate new box coordinates x1new_after_resizing, y1new_after_resizing, x2new_after_resizing,y2new_after_resizing?
And are there some tips about what H and H to choose for resizing? Mean of all images? Median?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get new coordinates from image size of `orig_width` and `orig_height` to `new_width` and `new_height`, you can use scale the box coordinates in the following way

`width_scaled = new_width/orig_width`
`height_scaled = new_height/orig_height`

`x1_new = x1*width_scaled`
`y1_new = y1*height_scaled`
`x2_new = x2*width_scaled`
`y2_new = y2*height_scaled`

You can plot these coordinates on the new image and check if you would like

There is no fixed method on how to choose the dimension of resizing images. It depends on various factors like the network, the GPU memory you have, batch size, and the shape of the smallest/largest image in the dataset. Ideally, it should not be too small/stretched out such that the images are incomprehensible or extremely stretched out

You can refer to [this](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_Image_resolution_should_I_use_for_training_for_deep_neural_network) post to get an idea of image resizing